# mysql HAVING group for multiple LIKE conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, having

I have a list of items that each contain a related to a list of tags.

I can retrieve these items by filtering the tag:

```
HAVING (GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name) LIKE '%$tag%')
```

So a list of **tag.names** for "ITEM x" could be: shoes, sandals, heel, black, beautiful

And the **$tag** that I'm searching for is: "**shoes**" - which would give me the "ITEM x".

But what happens when the user searches for tags with more than 1 word? ie. "**nice black shoes**". The condition above wouldn't deliver the result.

I understand that I can explode each word to have individual terms, but what to I do then, this?:

```
HAVING (GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name) LIKE '%$tag1%' OR GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name) LIKE '%$tag2%' OR GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name) LIKE '%$tag3%')
```

Where **$tag1** = nice , **$tag2** = black , **$tag2** = shoes

It seems to me that defining the GROUP_CONCAT x times (3 in the example) could be a bit consuming?

Any ideas?

Please note that I am using "**HAVING**" not "**WHERE**".

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Posting the full query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT i.id 
                , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.name ORDER BY t.stats_items DESC), ',', 3) as tagList
                FROM items AS i
                LEFT JOIN tag_rel AS tr ON (tr.item = i.id)
                LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = tr.tag)
                GROUP BY i.id 
                HAVING (GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) LIKE '$tag%')
                ORDER by i.DESC LIMIT 0, 120");
```

Answer (score 4):

A cleaner approach would be **not** searching in a string

```
HAVING sum(tag.name = 'nice') > 0
AND sum(tag.name = 'black') > 0
AND sum(tag.name = 'shoes') > 0
```

or

```
WHERE tag.name in ('nice','black','shoes')
HAVING count(distinct tag.name) = 3
```

Comment: +1. If you have an array-type of strings to look for check for them and don't go for `LIKE`.

Comment: This isn't working for me, It gives me 0 results :-( I'm going to update the post with my full query